# Python 2.7: fsolve sometimes returns the initial guess instead of the solution:

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, equation

I am trying to solve a set of nonlinear equations. I have to solve it for different parameters. Most of the time everything seems to work fine. Like in this case:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

p=3
x_diff=3.32
y_diff=-1.93
z_diff=0.64

def cubic(c):
    r=c[0]
    u=c[1]

    F=np.empty((2))
    F[0]=y_diff*cos(u)-x_diff*sin(u)
    F[1]=r+cos(u)*x_diff+y_diff*sin(u)+(r**(2*p-1))*(a**2)*p+z_diff*p*(r**(p-1))*a
    return F

cGuess=np.array([3.,2.])
c=fsolve(cubic,cGuess)


x=cubic(c)
```

In the end I tested the result by inserting it into the function cubic(). For the parameters used above the function gives something close to zero as it should.
But if I change the Parameter x_diff, y_diff and z_diff. fsolve returns the initial Guess as a solution, which is not the solution to the set of equation as you can see if you insert it in the function cubic().

```
x_diff=-6.15
y_diff=-2.11
z_diff=0.13
```

I am quite new to python, so it might be just a stupid mistake, but I can't find it. I really need this to work so thank you for every help!
Thanks!

Comment: `p` is not defined. Please define it (is it a typo or a parameter?).

Comment: oh yes I am sorry, that is a typo. p is a parameter e.g. p=3

Comment: Now I get `a` undefined :-)

Comment: a is about 0.002. I am sorry I forgot those two. I learned meanwhile that fsolve also gives me a message if something goes wrong. :) I f I display mesg it tells me: 'The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the improvement from the last ten iterations.'(I have found another way now how to get the results I need. But thanks a lot for having a look at this!!) But just in general: this message means propbably it can't find the proper solution with those parameter? In this case should I try to use another solving algorithm?

Comment: `c = fsolve(cubic, cGuess, full_output=True)` returns an output with solution `[3.776248  , 2.61501774]` and the message is `'The solution converged.'`. SciPy 1.1.0, Python 3.6.

Comment: did you calculate this with the second set of parameters or the first?

Comment: The first set of parameters, sorry.